# Expressão regular para número

Tags: php

Eu tenho algumas strings da seguinte forma:

```
99-01[10-10-2010]
59-06[11-12-2016]
```

Até ai tudo bem.

O que eu preciso, é via PHP e expressão regular, substituir qualquer caracter antes daquele primeiro hiffen (-), para algum texto qualquer, apenas do primeiro. Ficando por exemplo

```
ALL-01[10-10-2010]
ALL-06[11-12-2016]
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 6):

Utilize a função `preg_replace()` para fazer a substituição com uma regex `/\d+-/`, a parte importante é informar o quarto argumento que é o número de substiuição que serão feitas.

`\d+-` significa encontar na string um ou mais digitos seguidos de um traço em qualquer parte da string.

```
<?php
   $str = '99-01[10-10-2010] ALL-06[11-12-2016]';
   $str = preg_replace('/\d+-/', 'ALL-', $str, 1);
  echo $str;
```

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/GP7qPL)

Se string tiver várias linhas pode resolver de outra forma, pegando apenas o padrão especificado apenas no inicio de cada linha com o modificaro `s`.

```
<?php

$str = "99-01[10-10-2010]
59-06[11-12-2016]
99[333]
3333-ABC[99]88-XX";

$str = preg_replace('/^\d+-/s', 'ALL-', $str);

echo $str;
```

[Exemplo 2](http://ideone.com/k1etdi)

Answer (score 4):

Sei que você pediu uma *RegEx*, e o @rray postou a solução que faz exatamente o que você pediu (e que já levou o meu +1). De qualquer forma acho importante comentar que o PHP já tem uma solução feita como uma luva para o seu caso específico, e que não precisa de *RegEx*.

Basta isso, limpíssimo e curto de escrever:

```
'ALL'.strstr( '99-01[10-10-2010]', '-' );
```

Um código exemplo:

```
$s = '99-01[10-10-2010]';
echo 'ALL'.strstr( $s, '-' );
```

Iterando um *array*:

```
$strings = array(
    '99-01[10-10-2010]',
    '29-02[10-11-2011]',
    '95-03[10-12-2013]',
    '88-04[10-10-2015]',
    '59-06[11-12-2016]'
);

foreach( $strings as $s ) echo 'ALL'.strstr( $s, '-' );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ZDc8LA)**.